# Sub query with no result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two query that I would like to combine into one.

**Query 1:** `SELECT Quantity FROM Table1 WHERE IdProduct = 1234`

**Query 2:** `SELECT Supplier FROM Table2 WHERE IdProduct = 1234`

**Here is what I have done:**

```
SELECT
   bloc1.Quantity AS qty,
   bloc2.Supplier AS supplier
FROM    
   (SELECT Quantity FROM Table1 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) bloc1,
   (SELECT Supplier FROM Table2 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) bloc2
```

Most of the time everything goes well, but unfortunately, sometimes one of the two query return no result... In this specific case, the two query *"fail"*.

Comment: There's no join condition in your main query. Do you want a cross join? A full outer join?

Comment: What's the version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing a `CROSS JOIN` of the results of the 2 queries.
So if any of them returns no rows, the result is no rows.

Instead use the result of the 2 queries as columns if you are sure that they will return only 1 row:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT Quantity FROM Table1 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) qty,
  (SELECT Supplier FROM Table2 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) supplier
```

Answer (score 1):

U can join the two tables **table1** and **table2** u can do:

```
 SELECT qty,sup
    FROM   (SELECT Quantity as qty,supplier as sup
        FROM Table1 
        INNER JOIN Table2
        ON table1.IdProduct=table2.IdProduct AND IdProduct=1234);
```

u can check this for more information on joins in mysql https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Answer (score 0):

It's remarkable to me that slapping those queries together like that ever works.  But if you want it to survive a lack of records in one of these tables, you'll need an `OUTER JOIN` of some kind.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a "full outer join". Unfortunately MySQL does not implement full outer joins (why in this day and age?).

Anyway, you can simulate it with the workaround:

```
SELECT
   bloc1.Quantity AS qty,
   bloc2.Supplier AS supplier
FROM (SELECT Quantity FROM Table1 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) bloc1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Supplier FROM Table2 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) bloc2 on 1 = 1
UNION
SELECT
   bloc1.Quantity AS qty,
   bloc2.Supplier AS supplier
FROM (SELECT Quantity FROM Table1 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) bloc1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT Supplier FROM Table2 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) bloc2 on 1 = 1
```

In MySQL 8.x you can remove the redundancy (and somewhat shorten it) by using CTEs. For example:

```
with
bloc1 as (SELECT Quantity FROM Table1 WHERE IdProduct = 1234),
bloc2 as (SELECT Supplier FROM Table2 WHERE IdProduct = 1234)
SELECT
   bloc1.Quantity AS qty,
   bloc2.Supplier AS supplier
FROM bloc1 LEFT JOIN bloc2 on 1 = 1
UNION
SELECT
   bloc1.Quantity AS qty,
   bloc2.Supplier AS supplier
FROM bloc1 RIGHT JOIN bloc2 on 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select 
(SELECT Quantity FROM Table1 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) as qty,
(SELECT Supplier FROM Table2 WHERE IdProduct = 1234) as supplier
```